# ASP NET CORE 5 EF com DLL de conexao a banco de dados

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp-net-core

É possível usar uma DLL de conexão ao banco de dados num projeto ASP NET CORE 5 com Entity Framework?

Tenho uma DLL chamado "BancoDados" como posso usar os métodos dessa DLL no contexto do projeto.

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ChamadosContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer("**NOME DA DLL**")));
    
    services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.Configure<CookieTempDataProviderOptions>(options => {
        options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    });
}
```

Comment: Você não conseguiu referenciar a biblioteca para dentro do seu projeto e instanciar seus objetos?

Comment: Não dessa forma... Essa dll provavelmente se chama `BancoDados` por implementar a camada de infra de um repositório. Você pode fazer a conexão com o banco e utilizar as classes e métodos públicos que estão disponíveis nela...

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção, Eu consigo usar os objetos da classe, a minha dúvida é como faço isso, indicando ao meu contexto que a conexão é através da DLL. Não sei se foi claro, basicamente eu preciso que o EF use a DLL quando fizer migrações e atualizações no banco de dados.

Comment: Não vai, a menos que as variáveis de conexão estejam em constantes na DLL, o que é pouco provável e nenhum um pouco recomendado... As migrações vão ter seu registro no próprio banco de dados e não da DLL, o que você está pretendendo não faz nenhum sentido, por que você acha que precisa fazer isso e dessa forma?

Comment: Ps.: Se as entidades ou models estiverem nessa dll... você não vai conseguir alterar sem um override, logo não tem impacto nas migrações, a menos que você crie novas

Answer (score -1):

> É possível usar uma DLL de conexão ao banco de dados num projeto ASP NET CORE 5 com Entity Framework?

Sim, e você com certeza já o fez. O Entity Framework, por exemplo, é **"uma DLL de conexão ao banco de dados"**. Segundo as boas práticas, seu projeto também deverá ter uma camada de repositório, que por sua vez também será **"uma DLL de conexão ao banco de dados"**.

Entretanto, o conceito e uso não parecem estar claros para vc. O primeiro passo ao tentar usar um método deve ser sempre olhar a sua documentação, permitindo não só entender se é adequado para a sua necessidade ou se há uma alternativa melhor na mesma classe.

O método `UseSqlServer` que vc está usando pode ser encontrado [neste link](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/v5.0.1/src/EFCore.SqlServer/Extensions/SqlServerDbContextOptionsBuilderExtensions.cs). Pela documentação dos métodos é possível perceber que há 2 sobrecargas: uma recebe uma uma `string` (mais especificamente uma `ConnectionString`) e a outra um `DbConnection` (um objeto de conexão à base de dados).

Sendo assim, a primeira correção deveria ser à linha `services.AddDbContext<ChamadosContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer("**NOME DA DLL**")));`, podendo ser substituída por algo como `services.AddDbContext<SchoolContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("NomeDaConexaoNoAppSettings")));`.

Outra alternativa seria utilizar um método (que pode estar nessa sua DLL) que retorne uma `connection string` ou um `DbConnection`, mas em ambos os casos os dados de conexão precisariam estar fixos na DLL, o que, além de não ser nada recomendável, também não faz muito sentido.

O que vc parece querer é que os seus `models` e `DbContext` estejam em uma DLL (ou projeto à parte). E isso funcionará normalmente ao especificar `AddDbContext<ChamadosContext>`. Tanto a aplicação quando as migrações usarão o `DbContext` especificado na aplicação.